# different coefficients and number of df for the same lambdas (glmnet)

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

Using the same lambda in lasso regression from glmnet package in R leads to different results.
When I set a default number of lambdas to 100 my minimum lambda is 0.03196 and df=54. When I set it to 200, minimum lambda is the same but I get only 53 df.
It's even more odd when lambda is chosen manually. When lambda is set to 0.03196, it results in Df=49. It also means that for each method (for which the parameters are the same) I get different coefficients.

Below is the example:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(162)

var_num=100
obs_num=50

#Generating data:
x <- matrix(rnorm(var_num*obs_num), ncol=var_num)
var_num_half=floor(var_num/2)
y= x %*% c( rep(1,var_num_half),rep(0,var_num-var_num_half)) + rnorm(obs_num)

#Using lasso with 100 and 200 lambdas:
lasso100 <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="gaussian", nlambda=100)  
lasso200 <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="gaussian", nlambda=200)

#Difference in number of Df for the same minimum lambda:
df <- c(lasso100$df[length(lasso100$lambda)], lasso200$df[length(lasso200$lambda)])

#Applying minimum lambdas from examples above manually:
lambdas <- c(lasso100$lambda[length(lasso100$lambda)], lasso200$lambda[length(lasso200$lambda)])
lasso <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="gaussian", lambda=lambdas)

#Difference in coefficents for all three approaches
coef(lasso200)[,length(lasso200$lambda)]["V1"]
coef(lasso100)[,length(lasso100$lambda)]["V1"]
coef(lasso)[,length(lasso$lambda)]["V1"]
```

My questions:

1. Why does it result in a diffrent number of df with the same lambda when I change nlambda parameter?
2. Why the number of df is different when I use the same lambda but chosen manually?